# Visualization of an upper triangular matrix without the zeros

Tags: visualization

I am trying to find a suitable way to visualize the upper half of a matrix. Can anyone be of help ? I have a matrix of the form M[i,j], i=1,....,n and j=i,...,n
Using ListPlot3D is not helping as it is also plotting all the M[i,j]=0 for j < i

Comment: You may want MatrixPlot or ArrayPlot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318529/plotting-only-upper-lower-triangle-of-a-heatmap. Something like this will be helpful

Comment: Hi, Array plot will work, but I was looking for something like

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayPlot[
 Table[If[i > j, 0, RandomReal[]], {i, 10}, {j, 10}],
 ColorFunction -> Function[z, If[z == 0, White, Hue[z]]],
 Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Primarily to illustrate [`BarLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html). You can omit the text placement. It is just to compare with bar legend.

```
sa = SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i < j :> RandomReal[10], {10, 10}];
Legended[MatrixPlot[sa, Mesh -> All, ColorRules -> {0 -> White}, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {0, 10}]] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MeshStyle -> White, Frame -> True, 
  Epilog -> {Text[
       NumberForm[Extract[sa, ##], 
        2], {#[[2]], 10 - #[[1]]} + {-0.5, 0.5}] & /@ 
     sa["NonzeroPositions"]}], BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 10}}]]
```

[image]

Note

- you can also  use `UpperTriangularize` to make upper triangular matrix
- you have to deal with different coordinate systems for `Plot` and `MatrixPlot`
- `ColorFunctionScaling->False` was done to get the `BarLegend` and `MatrixPlot` to display same scale

Comment: Thank you so much guys. This is very helpful